# Send request to download file, catch response in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, jquery, download

In a Rails2 Webapp, I am creating in javascript a form to forge a request to download a file. In the controller, I render the response using send_file so the file is downloaded.

There is a rather long process going on looking up the file to download and meanwhile I have the client waiting for the file to start being downloaded. For this reason, as soon as the client clicks the download button I display a small massage saying "Requesting file...".

Problem:
How can I (on javascript side) know when the response is rendered (aka the file starts to download) so I can hide the message I am displaying? I use ajax everywhere and I throw the showMessage method in the "before" part of the call and the hideMessage in the "complete" part of the jquery ajax call. But since I cannot request a file to be downloaded with an ajax call I have to do it trough a form but then I don't know how to realize when I get the repsonse back (or the file starts to download)

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to send a cookie along with the file. Some javascript code checks the cookie periodically. When javascript gets the cookie, you know the downloading begins.

You can find sample javascript code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120121/file-download-start-event-in-struts) (server code in Java) and [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser.aspx) (server code in ASP.NET).

In Rails, the cookie could be sent like this:

```
cookies['download_token'] = params[:download_token]
send_data ...
```